# How to calculate the black / white ratio of pixels inside a contour

Tags: c++, opencv

How is it possible to calculate the black / white ratio of the pixels inside the outline of a contour (not the bounding box)?

The image is pre-processed with `cv::threshold(src, img, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);` and then inverted `img = 255 - img;`

I look for the retangular outline of the table (contour) via `cv::RETR_EXTERNAL`.. I want to calculate the black pixels inside the contour

There can be other components in the image so I can't just count all non-zero pixels

This is the original image before binarized and inverted

[image]

Comment: Could you precise what you mean exactly by "the black / white ratio of a contour"? In image processing, contours are usually defined by a 1-pixel wide curve which makes the question confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not an expert in openCV so I might not be 100% correct in the terms.. but I need to calculate the ratio of black and white pixels inside a contour

Comment: A contour is defined as being the white pixels. White pixel = contour, Black pixel = no contour. So I'm still confused. Would you have a visual example of what you call a contour with black and white pixels? So maybe we can agree on the vocabulary and see if I can help you :)

Comment: Ok, what if I say I would like to copy all pixels inside a contour curve to a mask?

Comment: I want to invert all pixels inside a contour if the black and white ratio is higher than `x`

Comment: create a mask with `cv::drawContours` with thickness `cv::FILLED`, then use `cv::countNonZero` with the mask (and the inverted one)

Comment: @miki could you show an example? :)

Comment: did you run `cv::findContours` or you start from the b/w mask given by the threshold?

Comment: I get this part.. :) `cv::drawContours(mask, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);`

Comment: I have found the contours.. And in the previous comment I draw the contour in an empty mask

Comment: what do you intend exactly for "black pixels inside the contour"? Do you have "holes"? an example of the thresholded image whould help

Comment: There might be holes in the "surface".. I just want to calculate the painted pixels inside the contour

Comment: Have added the original image before binarized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's some confusion about terminology. A contour is simply a sequence of points. If you draw them as a closed polygon (e.g. with `cv::drawContours`), all the points inside the polygon will be *white*.

You can however use this mask to count the white or black pixels on your thresholded image:

```
cv::Mat1b bw_image = ...

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(bw_image, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::Mat1b contour_mask(bw_image.rows, bw_image.cols, uchar(0));
    cv::drawContours(contour_mask, contours, i, Scalar(255), cv::FILLED);

    int total_white_inside_contour = cv::countNonZero(mask);
    int white_on_image_inside_contour = cv::countNonZero(bw_image & mask);
    int black_on_image_inside_contour = total_white_inside_contour - white_on_image_inside_contour;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate the white and black ratio of a contour, because what is a contour? A group of white pixels which are connected which each other calls contour, so a contour does not contain any black pixel if it does, it calls hole inside the contour.

And also a contour does not have a specific shape.

So you can do it by [Bounding Rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) the rectangle around the contour then you will be to calculate the black and white ratio inside the rectangle.

[image]